# Make sure only 1 thread running in Java

Tags: java, spring

I'm doing a function in a Spring backend program, users can invoke to launch a background thread but only 1 thread is allowed at a time. If a request comes when there's already a thread running, just do nothing.

My service code looks like this:

```
@Service
public class AssertionService {
    // if background indexing is running
    private boolean indexing = false;

    Runnable indexAll = () -> {
        // do calculating jobs
        indexing = false;
    }

    public synchronized void doIndex() {
        if (!indexing) {
            indexing = true;
            new Thread(indexAll).start();
        } else {
            logger.debug("An indexing thread already running at background");
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's still not perfect, when doIndex() is called with indexing = true, the thread may just finish so setting indexing = false, the doIndex() misses an invocation.

But as long as there's only 1 thread, there's fine. So can anyone have a look at the code and let me know if there's any problem?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what `indexAll` does, but this looks like an unavoidable race condition -- is there any difference between skipping indexing when the thread has 100ms to run vs 1ms? If there's work that must be done, but in a single threaded way, put the work on a queue in doIndex and have a thread to wait for the work.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to put the job in a queue now. Yes there's a race condition since indexing is accessed from indexAll and doInex in different threads. But as long as 1 thread only is guaranteed, that will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides support for running background tasks with a TaskExecutor, no need to do this by hand with Threads and Runnable. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling-task-executor

Configure the thread pool to only have a single available thread.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I think I tried with this but still > 1 threads being launched. I'll try it again, thanks!

Comment: Hi Kevin, I used SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor and set ConcurrencyLimit = 1, upon receiving the request I call executor.execute(indeAll), but the thing is, all requests will be queued and executed one by one, this is not what I want. If there's a job currently running, all the requests received should just return (do nothing) instead of being queued.

Comment: Looks like there's a bounded ThreadPool. I'm trying that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with

```
ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0, MILLISECONDS,
            new SynchronousQueue<>(),
            new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());

public Boolean indexAll() {
    try {
        executorService.execute(indexAll);
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException e){
        logger.debug("An index threading is already running at background");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```